# Affine Cipher Output in Java

Tags: java, encryption, brute-force

The program I have written in `Java` with `BlueJ` deciphers any string cipher made up of the 26 lowercase letters (a, b, c, ..., x, y, z), given that the text has been encrypted using an `affine cipher`. It uses a brute force search, trying all possible keys.

The program works correctly as it should, but I am having trouble with the output.

I am supposed to output the "Encryption Key" and "Decryption Equation" after each brute force search, but I cannot seem to figure out how.

This is sample output of what I have currently:

```
Decrypting the cipher text:
vwduwljudeehghyhubwklqjlfrxogilqgsohdvhuhwxuqdqbeoxhsulqwviruydxowdqgdodupghvljqedvhgrqzklfkedqnbrxghflghrqldpvhwwlqjxsvdihkrxvhfr

Plaintext:
uvctvkitcddgfgxgtavjkpikeqwnfhkpfrngcugtgvwtpcpadnwgrtkpvuhqtxcwnvcpfcnctofgukipdcugfqpyjkejdcpmaqwfgekfgqpkcougvvkpiwruchgjqwugeq

Hit 0 to continue search or 1 to stop:
0

Plaintext:
yhsphmupsbbctczcpahdmfumkoqntlmftxncsycpchqpfsfabnqcxpmfhylopzsqnhsftsnspwtcymufbsyctofidmkdbsfeaoqtckmtcofmswychhmfuqxyslcdoqycko

Hit 0 to continue search or 1 to stop:
0

...
... many lines later
...

Plaintext:
gfyhfqshyxxuvuduhafrqlsqwkenvtqlvjnuyguhufehlylaxneujhqlfgtkhdyenfylvynyhmvugqslxyguvklcrqwrxyloakevuwqvuklqymguffqlsejgyturkeguwk

Hit 0 to continue search or 1 to stop:
0

Plaintext:
startigrabbedeverythingicouldfindpleasereturnanyblueprintsforvaultandalarmdesignbasedonwhichbankyoudecideoniamsettingupsafehouseco

Hit 0 to continue search or 1 to stop:
1
```

This is sample output of what is supposed to be shown:

```
Decrypting the cipher text:
vwduwljudeehghyhubwklqjlfrxogilqgsohdvhuhwxuqdqbeoxhsulqwviruydxowdqgdodupghvljqedvhgrqzklfkedqnbrxghflghrqldpvhwwlqjxsvdihkrxvhfr

Encryption key: a = 1 b = 1
Decryption equation: x = 1 *(y - 1)

Plaintext:
uvctvkitcddgfgxgtavjkpikeqwnfhkpfrngcugtgvwtpcpadnwgrtkpvuhqtxcwnvcpfcnctofgukipdcugfqpyjkejdcpmaqwfgekfgqpkcougvvkpiwruchgjqwugeq

Hit enter to continue search or 'S' key to stop:
Encryption key: a = 3 b = 1
Decryption equation: x = 9 *(y - 1)

Plaintext:
yhsphmupsbbctczcpahdmfumkoqntlmftxncsycpchqpfsfabnqcxpmfhylopzsqnhsftsnspwtcymufbsyctofidmkdbsfeaoqtckmtcofmswychhmfuqxyslcdoqycko

Hit enter to continue search or 'S' key to stop:
Encryption key: a = 5 b = 1
Decryption equation: x = 21 *(y - 1)

...
... many lines later
...

Hit enter to continue search or 'S' key to stop:
Encryption key: a = 25 b = 2
Decryption equation: x = 25 *(y - 2)

Plaintext:
hgzigrtizyyvwvevibgsrmtrxlfowurmwkovzhvivgfimzmbyofvkirmghuliezfogzmwzozinwvhrtmyzhvwlmdsrxsyzmpblfwvxrwvlmrznhvggrmtfkhzuvslfhvxl

Hit enter to continue search or 'S' key to stop:
Encryption key: a = 1 b = 3
Decryption equation: x = 1 *(y - 3)

Plaintext:
startigrabbedeverythingicouldfindpleasereturnanyblueprintsforvaultandalarmdesignbasedonwhichbankyoudecideoniamsettingupsafehouseco

Hit enter to continue search or 'S' key to stop: S

The plain text message below was encrypted with a = 1 and b = 3
startigrabbedeverythingicouldfindpleasereturnanyblueprintsforvaultandalarmdesignbasedonwhichbankyoudecideoniamsettingupsafehouseco
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class AffineCipher{
/**
* Prompts the user to enter a string of cipher text, along with the ablility
* to continue to search or to stop the search. The output or plaintext is 
* printed each time.
*/
public static void main(String[] args){
    int count = 1;
    int choice = 0;
    int change = 0;
    int stop = 1;
    int cont = 0;
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.printf("Decrypting the cipher text:%n");
    String input = kbd.next();
    System.out.printf("\n");

    while (choice != stop){
        while (choice == cont){
            if (count == 13){
                count = count + 2;
            }
            String deciphered = decrypt(input,change, count);
            System.out.println("Plaintext:");
            System.out.println(deciphered);
            System.out.printf("\n");

            if (count == 25){
                change = 1;
                count = 1;
            }
            System.out.printf("Hit 0 to continue search or 1 to stop:%n");
            choice = kbd.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("\n");
            count = count + 2;
        }
    }
}

/**
* Deciphers the string cipher text.
*/
static String decrypt(String input,int change, int count){
    if (change == 0){
        int firstKey = 0 + count;
        int secondKey = 1;
        int mod = 26;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BigInteger inverse = BigInteger.valueOf(count).modInverse(BigInteger.valueOf(mod));

        for (int in = 0; in < input.length(); in++){
            char character = input.charAt(in);                
            if (Character.isLetter(character)){
                int decoded = inverse.intValue() * (character - 'a' - secondKey + mod);                    
                character = (char) (decoded % mod + 'a');
            }
            builder.append(character);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    } else{
        int firstKey = 1;
        int mod = 26;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BigInteger inverse = BigInteger.valueOf(firstKey).modInverse(BigInteger.valueOf(mod));

        for (int in = 0; in < input.length(); in++){
            char character = input.charAt(in);
            if (Character.isLetter(character)){
                int decoded = inverse.intValue() * (character - 'a' - count + mod);
                character = (char) (decoded % mod + 'a');
            }
            builder.append(character);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.